# Cannot run application forever using PM2

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pm2

When I am running the application using npm start I can able to run the application without any error.

I have installed pm2 to run node from now on.

I am using the command PM2 start npm start:
[image]

then I am using PM2 logs npm command I am able to see the application running in the terminal:
[image]
 But when I'm running the browser nothing is running.

Nothing is also running when I'm running the browser.

Comment: By forever, do you mean untill the next reboot? Or, are you building something to run for the next x million years?

Comment: @SolarMike i want to run application for long time

Comment: Is this up to the next reboot? or must it restart after a reboot?

Comment: @SolarMike up to the next reboot

Answer (score 0):

Your npm start will most likely be a command with the node prefix, to run pm2 on a node project you'll have to `NODE_ENV=<insert env> pm2 start node server.js` and for react you'll have to pack/build your project and do `pm2 start http-server -p <insert port>`.

Other ways off running this forever is through nginx etc.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: pm2 start npm start gives name npm when pme logs npm running still not running in the browser

Comment: what are you trying to run, basically never pm2 start an npm script that rarely works out in my experience. As you can see it just built it for production and is in your `/dist folder` (end off your logs output) which means you can do `pm2 start http-server -p <insert port>.` as mentioned in my answer. Can you show your `npm start` script, then i can explain why :)